# decode and encode a json encoded array of coordinates using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, geospatial

i've built a server in java which accepts a json encoded array of coordinates respresented as an array containg latitude and longitude.

so it looks like this

```
[["48.72028","21.25768"],["48.71669000000001","21.253410000000002"]]
```

now i need to decode it into an array of Coordinate. Coordinate is com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate.

this array represents a polyline which is transformed into a polygon. the polyline is hundreds of points long. i also need to send the polygon encoded in json back to the client

until now i have used google gson, but it slow. the json decoding and encoding takes more time than the polygon transformation.

after a little googling i got the impression that jackson should be the fastest.

but as i'm a php developer where json decode and encode is just one line and this is my first time writing java, i have no idea how to use it.

how do you decode the json in an Coordinate[] array, and then encode similar array into json again?

thanks

Comment: Excuse me, I worked with Jackson to treat JSON data, but I've never seen JSON data in the format you gave. Is this a valid JSON data ? shouldn't it be something like: "field":"value" pairs ?

Comment: it's a json array. nothing unusual. what you describe is an object.

Comment: If you give the example you did in Gson I can help to transform it into Jackson

Comment: you can see the code here https://gist.github.com/bazo/5233194

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well your question, it's an array of arrays. I am not sure my approach here will work for you (sorry I don't have a test environment here). However, it works fine, with array of objects:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


  JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, ArrayList.class) ;


  List<List> results;

  try {
        results = (List<List>)mapper.readValue(jsonData, type);

        Coordinate[] coordinates = new Coordinate[results.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
       coordinates[i] = new Coordinate(Double.parseDouble((String)results.get(i).get(0)),Double.parseDouble((String)results.get(i).get(1)));
     }
  } catch (JsonParseException e) {
  } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
  } catch (IOException e) {
  }
```

I hope this helps

Comment: thanks, this works, but it is actually slower than using gson in most cases

Answer (score 1):

All you need is 2 simple annotations on the Coordinate class:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = Shape.ARRAY)
@JsonPropertyOrder({"x", "y"})
public static class Coordinate {
    public double x;
    public double y;

    public Coordinate() {}

    public Coordinate(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

public void test() throws IOException {
    List<Coordinate> p = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
    p.add(new Coordinate(1, 2));
    p.add(new Coordinate(3, 4));
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String writeValueAsString = mapper.writeValueAsString(p);
    System.out.println(writeValueAsString);

    CollectionType collectionType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, Coordinate.class);
    List<Coordinate> readValue = mapper.readValue(writeValueAsString, collectionType);
    assertEquals(readValue.size(), 2);
    assertEquals(readValue.get(0).x, 1, 0.0);
    assertEquals(readValue.get(0).y, 2, 0.0);
    assertEquals(readValue.get(1).x, 3, 0.0);
    assertEquals(readValue.get(1).y, 4, 0.0);
}
```

There's no intermediate process involved, Jackson does all the work for you. The @JsonFormat annotation tells Jackson that what you expect is an array instead of an object, and the @JsonPropertyOrder ensure that the properties are always decoded in the proper order. This has the added bonus that you can even encode your data with the same format!

If you don't have access to the Coordinate class to add those annotation, simply use the mix-in feature of Jackson.

Comment: that would be cool but i cant add annotations to a class from another library, can I?

Comment: Yes, using mix-ins: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations. That feature is made specially for that use case ;)